# yt-dlp prompt user for custom video quality

Tags: python, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

How can I create a python script that prompts the user for a video URL, asks the user to choose a specific video quality, and then download it to a (preferably) custom video file? Digging through their documentation has been unfruitful, and code examples on stack overflow weren't helpful either.

Here is my existing code:

```py
import yt_dlp


URL = input("URL: ")

# SOMEHOW PROMPT USER TO CHOOSE VIDEO FORMAT.

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
    ydl.download(URL)
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.